# Import variable initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder about why import a variable in python (python 3.4) has different result than importing a module and then referencing, more over why does a deep copy is made - and is there a way to bypass the copy (and not by defining a function that simply returns it)?

**a.py**

```
v = 1

def set():
    global v
    v = 3
```

**main.py**

```
import a
import b

a.set()
b.foo()
```

**b.py**

```
from  a import  v

def foo():
    print(v)
    print(a.v)
    print(id(v))
    print(id(a.v))
```

---

Output

```
1
3
1585041872
1585041904
```

Comment: So you want to alter the state of an imported module from the calling code. Why?

Comment: Configuration - I want to read configuration and then access it later.

Comment: Dynamic configuration changed by calling code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying a scalar value. This is not a problem specific to modules, it would work the same when simply passing the variable into a function and modifying it there.

The ***value*** `1` is imported from `a`, period. Whatever you do in `a` afterwards will not modify the value, because it's a simple immutable scalar value.

If `a.v` was an object, changes to this object would propagate to any variable holding a reference to it.

Comment: Just to clarify: changes to the object would propagate, but re-bining the variable to another object would not.

Answer (score 2):

Asked a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638246/understanding-from-import-behavior) myself, and with the help of others I figured out what it is. Here's what I found out. With `pydoc` links:

`from a import v` does not add a reference to `a.v`. Instead, it add a new variable to `b` as `b.v` with the value of `a.v` when `import` happened. Changing `a.v` later does not change the value of `b.v`.

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)

> The from form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus found.

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#from)

> The from form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the `import` clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, `ImportError` is raised.
>    4. otherwise, a reference to that value is stored **in the local namespace,** using the name in the as clause if it is present, otherwise using the attribute name

The keyword here is **in the local namespace**.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the sequence of events:

```
a.v = 1     # a.py: v = 1
b.v = a.v   # b.py: from a import v
a.v = 3     # a.set()
print(b.v)  # foo(): print(v)
print(a.v)  # foo(): print(a.v)
```

As you can see, `from a import v` actually binds `b.v` to a *value* from `a`, and later modification to the original variable don't affect the copy.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `import a`, you are creating a reference to the module. a.v is not copied. I change in one module is noticed in all modules. When you say `from  a import  v` you are making a copy of v at the time of the import. If either variable is changed, it is not reflected elsewhere.