# Understanding `from ... import ...` behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've encountered an interesting behavior regarding the `from ... import ...` syntax. It seems that when using this syntax, identifiers are imported as new identifiers, instead of references.

I've been writing Python for quite some time and have always avoided using this syntax, so this is quite unexpected for me. Instead I expected it to work the same as `import ...`.

Here is an example:

a.py

```
x = 0
```

b.py

```
from b import x

def f():
    print(x)
```

main.py

```
import a
import b

a.f()
b.x = 1
a.f()
```

The result is:

```
0
0
```

instead of

```
0
1
```

which I expected.

So does `from ... import ...` create a new variable, or does it make a reference to the variable?

I've searched the docs, Googled, searched around StackOverflow, but there doesn't seem to be a very clear answer to this question. Any links (especially Python docs) would be appreciated.

Comment: how can you use `from b import x
` in your `b.py` file

Comment: Why would the function in `a` access the name in `b`?

Comment: sorry guys, I've messed up `a` and `b` when posting. edited

Comment: Please moderator, I don't think this is a duplicate... Please read carefully ok?

Comment: (BTW, while it may not be a duplicate of the other question it's flagged with, I'm **certain** I've seen someone asking exactly this before, and that we do have a duplicate somewhere in our knowledge base; I'm looking for that, to be able to correct the flagging).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The thing is, whoever marked this question as a duplicate wasn't reading carefully. It's so depressing I have to explain why it is ___NOT___ a duplicate... also, would you mind finding the post you mentioned?

Comment: Yup, still working on it. Thing is, if I de-duplicate it now, then I can't give it a different duplicate flag later, which is why I'm holding off on removing the bad flag until I've found a correct one or given up.

Comment: The closest candidate I can recall is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168734/python-what-priority-does-global-have), which I remember because I answered it. It's not a great match.

Comment: ...okay, think I found something better. @MichaelKim, do you think this works?

Comment: @user2357112 I see your post, thanks. do you have a reference for _"identically-named new global variables"_ though? this is all i'm asking for

Comment: @CharlesDuffy uhh, link?

Comment: @MichaelKim, it's the new duplicate link -- replaced the old one; see the top of the post if you reload the page.

Comment: ["The `from` form ... goes through the list of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step (1), and **binds the name** in the **local namespace** to the **object** thus found."](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, you should use edits to prove why instead of simply stating why.

Comment: @Makoto, ...to be fair, the old duplicate link *was* pretty obviously wrong on its face; the new one is a stronger contender.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  I won't contest that, but this is more for future reference.  Users edit questions as "not a duplicate" but it doesn't actually mean anything to a passer-by.  Adding rationale would help everyone.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. The new one _is_ a duplicate, but the answer there didn't provide the Python doc reference I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the link!

Comment: @user2357112, perhaps you might add an answer on the other question? :)

Comment: I'm editing the post now...

Comment: Try making `x` a list of one element, `x = [0]`, and then change its value with `a.x[0] = 1` in the `main.py` script and see what happens.

Comment: @martineau thanks, but the issue here is how `from ... import ...` behaves, not how to solve the problem. using `import ...` would do it anyway

Comment: @MichaelKim, ...btw, as a rule, we tend to frown on including answers in questions (which prevents those answers from being commented on, flagged, voted on, &c. independently of the relevant question). If something is flagged as a duplicate of a question that isn't adequately answered, the Right Thing is to *add a proper answer to the other question*, not edit an answer into the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh well, ok..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy looks good now, I guess?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you!!! you really helped me out